# How to use OAuth2 with Restsharp for Lulu API

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I am trying to learn how to use the new Lulu api and am stuck on the OAuth2 authorization.  They give a sample in Curl but I am not familiar with it.  I found a response on a previous thread but it didn't seem to work for this application.  the Lulu Api documentation can be found at developers.lulu.com/public-docs but it is difficult to follow.  I have many years experience with C# for desktop applications but am new to using Rest API's or Oauth.

This is my current code generated from other questions and answers on stackoverflow

```
var client = new RestClient($"https://api.sandbox.lulu.com/auth/realms/glasstree/ptotocol/openid connect");
string clientKeySecret=" Basic ZjJjNDdmMTctOWMxZi00ZWZlLWIzYzEtMDI4YTNlZTRjM2M3OjMzOTViZGU4LTBkMjQtNGQ0Ny1hYTRLWM4NGM3NjI0OGRiYw=='";
            var request = new RestRequest()
            {
                Method = Method.GET
            };
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", clientKeySecret);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var strJSONData = response.Content;
```

When I run it strJSONData is null.

(ps. the clientKeySecret variable is not the real one)

Here is what the documentation says about how to request a token:

Authorization
The Lulu API uses OpenID Connect, an authentication layer built on top of OAuth 2.0. Instead of exchanging username and password, the API uses JSON Web Token (JWT) to authorize client requests.

To interact with the API you need a client-key and a client-secret. Open the Client Keys & Secret page to generate them.

Generate a Token
To interact with the API you first have to generate an OAuth token. This requires the following parameters:

client_key
client_secret
grant-type must be set to client_credentials
You have to send a POST request to the token endpoint a special Authorization header. For your convenience, you can copy the authorization string directly from your API Keys page:

```
curl -X POST https://api.lulu.com/auth/realms/glasstree/protocol/openid_connect/token \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Authorization:  Basic ZjJjNDdmMTctOWMxZi00ZWZlLWIzYzEtMDI4YTNlZTRjM2M3OjMzOTViZGU4LTBkMjQtNGQ0Ny1hYTRjLWM4NGM3NjI0OGRiYw=='
```

Comment: Send a POST request not a GET